# Finding $y=b$ that dissects the area between $ y=36, y=12, y=x^2$ into 2 equal halves.

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Finding $y=b$ that dissects the area between $ y=36, y=12, y=x^2$ .

what I did is solving the following equation:

$\int_{0}^{6} 36-x^2\,dx$ - $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{b}} b-x^2\,dx$ = $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{b}} b-x^2\,dx$ - $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{12}} 12-x^2\,dx$.

and the answer I got is:

b= $(108 + 0.5*12^{1.5})^{2/3}$ (I would like If someone can edit that) 
but for some reason the answer is wrong. what is my mistake?

this is a picture for clearing the idea:

[image]

Comment: What is the "correct answer"? I did it myself and checked with wolfram alpha, $b$ you got is correct.

Comment: Your answer is right; it can also be written as $(108+12\sqrt{3})^{2/3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it may be easier to do the integral with respect to $y.$ so i am going to try that. what we need is $b$ such that $12 < b < 36$ and $$\int_{12}^{36} \sqrt y \, dy = 2 \int_{12}^b \sqrt y \, dy.$$ this is the same as $$36^{3/2} - 12^{3/2} = 2\left(b^{3/2} - 12^{3/2}\right) \to b = \left(\frac{(36)^{3/2} + (12)^{3/2}}{2}\right)^{2/3} = 25.502.$$

p.s. i had a friend in grad school by the name of adbdel ghani mehilia from algeria.

Comment: yeah, its the same answer i got. but for somehow I need to put the answer electronically, and maybe the notations weren't right. thank you.

Comment: @FirasAliAbdelGhani,  thanks fires. never knew the history of the name abdel ghani. i don't think friend was slave to the rich; he is rich. he is a prof at the some canadian university in saudi now.